How can I disambiguate a constructor call with parameter from a named instance creation?
In this example, the last line fails to compile. I understand why, but I wonder how I can make the compiler understand that I want to call Class(const int &) to create an unnamed instance, instead of trying to call the undefined default constructor and creating an instance named i:
struct Class {
    Class(const int &) {}
};

void foo() {
    int i;

    // Works
    Class(int(i));

    // Fails
    Class(i);
}

Error in MSVC:
C2371   'i': redefinition; different basic types
E0291   no default constructor exists for class "Class"


The second one does not call Class's constructor, it creates a variable called i of type Class.

Isn't this the well-known "most vexing parse"?

@ChrisMM if you read the last line of my question, you will see that I know that. My question is, how can I avoid that.

If you watched this... https://youtu.be/7DTlWPgX6zs?si=5M58eI7XwpZbKYax

@FridayPie I just did, and now I wish I hadn't...

You need to use brace initialization so that the grammar does not think you are trying to create an object named i of type Class. For you, that means
Class{i};

will create an unnamed temporary object that will be destroyed at the end of the full expression.

Another option: (Class(i));
Braces can have different semantics than parentheses in some cases (not in yours), and I'd rather not think about this in general.
